# Cast between List<MyType> and List<IMyType>

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I'm trying to work around the lack of support for return type covariance in C# as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319663/why-c-doesnt-allow-inheritance-of-return-type-when-implementing-an-interface/1320710#1320710) question and the first two answers to it.  For the most part I'm not having any problems setting up the casts, but one property where I'm using a list of objects/interfaces is stymieing my efforts.

What do I need to do in order to make the casts for `IFoo.manyBars` work?

```
public interface IBar
{
}

public interface IFoo
{
    IBar aBar { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IBar> manyBars { get; set; }
}

class CBar : IBar
{
}

class CFoo : IFoo
{
    public CBar aBar { get; set; }


    //this cast works
    IBar IFoo.aBar 
    {
        get { return aBar; }
        set { aBar = (CBar)value; }
    }

    public List<CBar> manyBars { get; set; }

    //the compiler can't cast either of these
    List<IBar> IFoo.manyBars
    {
        get { return (List<IBar>)manyBars; }
        set { manyBars = (List<CBar>)value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  You will have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the source file, if it's not there already.

```
List<IBar> IFoo.manyBars
{
    get { return manyBars.Cast<IBar>().ToList(); }
    set { manyBars = value.Cast<CBar>().ToList(); }
}
```

Note that this will allocate and copy a new array on **each access** to the property.  If this is not what you want, you should consider an alternative approach, such as exposing the property using the type `IEnumerable<IBar>`.

Using `List<IBar>` also means someone might try to do `anObject.manyBars.Remove(0)` which will do **absolutely nothing** to the list stored in `anObject`, since a copy is returned.

Comment: Switching my interface to an IEnumerable<IBar> isn't a problem, will doing this circumvent the problem with remove that using Linq to do a cast results in.

Comment: Sort of -- users of the class will be unable to remove items, since the `IEnumerable<T>` interface exposes no remove mechanism.  So it will be *less surprising* to users in that they cannot even *try* to remove items.

Comment: I guess I can live with that since the IFoo/IBar consumer is what I'm trying to encapsulate, and adding Add/Remove methods to the interface doesn't seem like it should pose any major problems.  The remainder of the CFoo and COtherFoo applications can continue to use the List<CBar>/List<COtherBar> versions.

Comment: I ran into something odd.  While I can do this cast  `(IEnumerable<IBar>)manyBars` directly with my trivial example class, with the more complex class in my app the cast fails unless I convert the list to an array first like this:   `(IEnumerable<IBar>)manyBars.ToArray()`.  I don't know what in my class is responsible for this, but since even with the extra indirection in the cast I'm not copying objects I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You would be better off doing `manyBars.Cast<IBar>()` since this will not create a completely new list on every call.  It's much more memory-efficient.

Comment: @cdhowie  wait what.  Isn't that the opposite of what you put in your answer?

Comment: Not if we are talking about the getter:  `IEnumerable<IBar> IFoo.manyBars { get { return manyBars.Cast<IBar>(); } set { /* unchanged from my code above */ } }`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a copy:

```
get { return manyBars.OfType<IBar>().ToList(); } 
set { manyBars = value.Cast<CBar>().ToList(); }
```

but you can't cast that instance.  If you could cast that instance, what happens when I try to `Add` an IBar that is not a CBar.

Comment: I'm aware this is somewhat brittle, although in practice users of CFoo/CBar and COtherFoo/COtherBar will be isolated.  Sharing a chunk of code written for the former with a related project using the latter was a last minute requirement change, so I'm limited in the scope of my refactoring in the quest for elegance.

Comment: Well, use Cast if you want it to throw when there's a problem.  Use OfType if you want it to filter out invalid items.  That's pretty much your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could create a new list for returning:

```
return new List<IBar>(manyBars);
```

Although remember that although the objects will be the same, you will be retrieving a different list, so you'll need to be careful about adding/removing objects from the list.

Comment: Unfortunately my IFoo consumer needs to be able to add/delete from the list, so creating a new copy isn't a viable option.

Comment: OK, but be careful because the other answers have the same issue.  Can you change the list declaration to "public List<IBar> manyBars { get; set; }"?

Comment: CBar and COtherBar both contain a number of methods/properties that aren't shared and which the IBar user doesn't care about, so I can't change the definitions of CFoo/COtherFoo to use a List<IBar>, without having to add casts all over the (much larger) portions of the codebases that consume the CFoo/COtherFoo objects.