# Why restricting return type for method and property inheritance so that descendants are not allowed?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following hypothetical situation:

```
class ClassParent { }
interface IClassProvider { ClassParent Get(); }
```

Why is this then illegal IClassProvider implementation:

```
class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider
{
    ClassChild Get() { return this; }
}
```

It also doesn't work for inheriting properties and implementing base class instead of an interface like in the example.

ClassChild *is* ClassParent. Why does it not compile then? The compiler is clearly aware of a compile-time type of a class, that's why the following works:

```
void DoSomething(object o) { ... };
void DoSomething(ConcreteClass c) { ... };

DoSomething(new ConcreteClass()); //Calls the second overload of the method because of static type resolving
```

In layered scenarios this forces me to have a bunch of proxy-methods and needlessly clutter my code when the underlying situation is clear. Frankly I can't think of any problems or ambiguities if that was supported. I would be happy with compile-time (static) resolution, like it works with overloads in the second example.

Edit: I know that the compiler expects the following:

```
class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider
{
    ClassParent Get() { return this; }
}
```

and I know that it would work, I'm asking for an explanation why is it not supported or a scenario in which it would cause either a) problems or b)ambiguities worse than with overloads, which are supported.

Edit 2:
This is as it seems another duplicate of a same old question as answered by apparently MS himself in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319663/why-c-doesnt-allow-inheritance-of-return-type-when-implementing-an-interface). I'm marking @Euphoric 's post as answer because he provided a name for the feature which helped finding the "solution".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think feature you are looking for is name [Covariant Return Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)

As to "why" is it not implemented, noone knows. IMO this feature is not so needed, so it is simply not implemented.

And especialy in your case it can be easily solved using [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the name of a feature. I know of explicit interface implementation, my case was a much larger scenario, just simplified to fit a question.

Comment: I agree with this... I see no reason it shouldn't work, but with explicit interface implementation, it really doesn't need to because you can have a Get function on the class specifically for the interface and one specific for the class if you want the method to return ClassChild when you are using a ClassChild type.

Answer (score 2):

`IClassProvider`'s `Get()` method expects its implementers to return *anything* that inherits from, or is an instance of, `ClassParent`.

You're violating the contract stipulated by the interface by telling its implementer to only return objects of *one specific subclass* of `ClassParent`, which, due to the nature of single inheritance in classes, is why it isn't allowed.

Comment: I don't see how that would be a problem, can you give a scenario? As long as every ClassChild is ClassParent (and it is) there is no formal contract breaching. I could just the same implement it like the compiler likes and write `ClassParent Get() { return this; }` and I would always return a specific type of an instance.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly your question, you could implement something like this:

```
class ClassParent { }

    interface IClassProvider<T> where T: ClassParent
    {
        T Get();
    }

    class ClassChild : ClassParent,IClassProvider<ClassChild>
    {

        public ClassChild Get()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Or, to the more extreme (which gives you more type safety)

```
public class ClassParent { }

    interface IClassProvider<T> where T : ClassParent, IClassProvider<T>
    {
        T Get();
    }

    class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider<ClassChild>
    {

        public ClassChild Get()
        {
           return this;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

the second version is a *bit* more type safe because this wont compile:

```
public class SomeOtherChildClass : ClassParent { }

class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider<SomeOtherChildClass>
    {

        public SomeOtherChildClass Get()
        {
           return this;
        }
    }
```

you could however write something like this, so it's not exactly perfect:

```
public class SomeOtherChildClass : ClassParent, IClassProvider<SomeOtherChildClass> { //implementation }

class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider<SomeOtherChildClass>
    {

        public SomeOtherChildClass Get()
        {
           return something;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if type safety is exactly the correct term. 
What I wanted to achieve is an object that can be provided only it implements a provider.

Comment: Nice, templating return type and restricting it, +1. That would cause fewer lines of code than the explicit implementation solution (which requires two methods to implement) And I'm curious, why is the second option any "type safer" that the first?

Answer (score 1):

Now it makes sense.

The signature must match exactly, like this

```
class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider
{
    ClassParent Get() { return this; }
}
```

Comment: Of course I know how it should look, my question was why is it not supported, i.e. what are the pontential problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with using explicit interface implementatin as Euphoric suggests?

```
class ClassChild : ClassParent, IClassProvider
{

   public ClassParent IClassProvider.Get()
   {
      return Get();
   }

   public ClassChild Get()
   {
      return this;
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of using expl. implemetation for that purpose. Thank you, that helped a lot. Although the question still remains as to why did MS think that covariant return type was not a good idea. The thread I posted cites that Anders didn't think that it was a good idea but gives no explanations why.