# "return this" using subtype for builders in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, builder

Can I make this C# code do what I want and have ShapeBuilder.color return the derived subtype of this?

```
class Shape {
    public String Color { get; private set; }

    public Shape(String color) {
        this.Color = color;
    }
}
class Circle : Shape {
    public int Radius { get; private set; }

    public Circle(String color, int radius) : base(color) {
        this.Radius = radius;
    }

    public override String ToString() {
        return String.Format("Circle c={0} r={1}", this.Color, this.Radius);
    }
}

class ShapeBuilder {
    // How can this function return the subtype, not just a ShapeBuilder?
    public ShapeBuilder color(String color) {
        this._color = color;
        return this;        
    }

    protected String _color;
}
class CircleBuilder : ShapeBuilder {
    public CircleBuilder radius(int radius) {
        this._radius = radius;
        return this;        
    }

    public Circle build() {
        return new Circle(_color, _radius);
    }

    protected int _radius;
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // This works.
        Circle c1 = new CircleBuilder().radius(5).build();
        Console.WriteLine("c1: " + c1);

        // This won't compile, because color returns ShapeBuilder rather than CircleBuilder.
        Circle c2 = new CircleBuilder().color("blue").build();
        Console.WriteLine("c2: " + c2);
    }
}
```

In Scala, I would do this:

```
case class Shape(val color: String)
class Circle(color: String, radius: Int) extends Shape(color)

class ShapeBuilder {
  def color(color: String): this.type = {
    this.color = color
    this
  }

  def build() = new Shape(color)

  protected var color: String = ""
}

class CircleBuilder extends ShapeBuilder {
  def radius(radius: Int): this.type = {
    this.radius = radius
    this
  }

  override def build() = new Circle(color, radius)

  protected var radius: Int = 0
}

object BuilderTest extends App {
    val c = new CircleBuilder().color("blue").radius(5).build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Shape {
  public String Color { get; private set; }

  public Shape(String color) {
    this.Color = color;
  }
}

public class Circle : Shape {
  public int Radius { get; private set; }

  public Circle(String color, int radius)
    : base(color) {
    this.Radius = radius;
  }

  public override String ToString() {
    return String.Format("Circle c={0} r={1}", this.Color, this.Radius);
  }
}

public class ShapeBuilder<TBuilder, TShape> 
    where TBuilder : ShapeBuilder<TBuilder, TShape> 
    where TShape : Shape {
  // How can this function return the subtype, not just a ShapeBuilder?
  public TBuilder color(String color) {
    this._color = color;
    return (TBuilder)this;
  }

  public virtual TShape build() {
    return default(TShape);
  }

  protected String _color;
}

public class CircleBuilder : ShapeBuilder<CircleBuilder, Circle> {
  public CircleBuilder radius(int radius) {
    this._radius = radius;
    return this;
  }

  public override Circle build() {
    return new Circle(_color, _radius);
  }

  protected int _radius;
}
```

Comment: This still won't compile: `Circle c2 = new CircleBuilder().color("blue").radius(3).build();`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with generics. The Scala version is nicest as it doesn't require generics at all to provide the derived type of `this` with `this.type`. Here is the C# version:

```
class Shape {
    public String Color { get; private set; }

    public Shape(String color) {
        this.Color = color;
    }

public override String ToString() {
        return String.Format("Shape c={0}", this.Color);
    }
}
class Circle : Shape {
    public int Radius { get; private set; }

    public Circle(String color, int radius) : base(color) {
        this.Radius = radius;
    }

    public override String ToString() {
        return String.Format("Circle c={0} r={1}", this.Color, this.Radius);
    }
}

interface Builder<T> {
    T build();
}
abstract class AbstractShapeBuilder<B, T> : Builder<T> where B : AbstractShapeBuilder<B, T> where T : Shape {
    abstract protected B getThis();

    abstract public T build();

    public B color(String color) {
        this._color = color;
        return getThis();        
    }

    protected String _color;
}
class ShapeBuilder : AbstractShapeBuilder<ShapeBuilder, Shape> {
    override protected ShapeBuilder getThis() { return this; }

    override public Shape build() {
        return new Shape(_color);
    }
}

abstract class AbstractCircleBuilder<B, T> : AbstractShapeBuilder<B, T> where B : AbstractCircleBuilder<B, T> where T : Circle {
    public B radius(int radius) {
        this._radius = radius;
        return getThis();        
    }

    protected int _radius;
}
class CircleBuilder : AbstractCircleBuilder<CircleBuilder, Circle> {
    override protected CircleBuilder getThis() { return this; }

    override public Circle build() {
        return new Circle(_color, _radius);
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("CircleBuilder: v1");

        Shape s1 = new ShapeBuilder().color("yellow").build();
        Console.WriteLine("s1: " + s1);

        Circle c1 = new CircleBuilder().color("blue").radius(3).build();
        Console.WriteLine("c1: " + c1);
    }
}
```

FYI, here is the Java version:

```
public class BuilderTest {
    public static class Shape {
        public Shape(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return String.format("shape. color=%s.", color);
        }

        public final String color;
    }
    public static class Circle extends Shape {
        public Circle(String color, int radius) {
            super(color);
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return String.format("circle. color=%s. radius=%d.", color, radius);
        }

        public final int radius;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface Builder<T> {
        public T build();
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractShapeBuilder<B extends AbstractShapeBuilder<B>> {
        protected abstract B getDerivedThis();

        public B color(String color) {
            this.color = color;
            return getDerivedThis();
        }

        String color;
    }
    public static class ShapeBuilder extends AbstractShapeBuilder<ShapeBuilder> implements Builder<Shape> {
        @Override protected ShapeBuilder getDerivedThis() { return this; }

        @Override public Shape build() {
            return new Shape(color);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractCircleBuilder<B extends AbstractCircleBuilder<B>> extends AbstractShapeBuilder<B> {
        public B radius(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
            return getDerivedThis();
        }

        int radius;
    }
    public static class CircleBuilder extends AbstractCircleBuilder<CircleBuilder> implements Builder<Circle> {
        @Override protected CircleBuilder getDerivedThis() { return this; }

        @Override public Circle build() { return new Circle(color, radius); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Shape s = new ShapeBuilder().color("red").build();
        System.out.println("s = " + s);

        Circle c = new CircleBuilder().color("blue").radius(5).build();
        System.out.println("c = " + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  Quick note on C# code: the `getThis()` method is not needed; simply cast `this` with the builder type parameter `B` -> `return ( B )this;`

Comment: That cast is not compiler guaranteed safe. Java's compiler will issue a warning on that cast, the Mono C# compiler does not give a warning, but it should.

Comment: Don't the generic constraints explicitly guarantee safety as it enforces the `B` type parameter is the same type as itself?  Could you provide an example that would throw an `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: I made a copy of the above C#, removed getThis(), changed the return to use the cast, and I can add this class which compiles and successfully triggers an InvalidCastException at runtime: class ShapeBuilder2 : AbstractShapeBuilder<ShapeBuilder, Shape> {
    override public Shape build() {
        return new Shape(_color);
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most idiomatic way to do this is to use `new` methods.

```
class ShapeBuilder {
    // How can this function return the subtype, not just a ShapeBuilder?
    public ShapeBuilder color(String color) {
        this._color = color;
        return this;        
    }

    protected String _color;
}
class CircleBuilder : ShapeBuilder {
    public new CircleBuilder color(String color) {
        return (CircleBuilder)base.color(color)
    }
}
```

Why is this a good way to do it?

Generics are bad in this situation because they make it more complicated to write code that operates polymorphically on different ShapeBuilders. Generic base classes like this tend to force the calling code to also be generic without major benefit.

`ShapeBuilder s = new CircleBuilder(); s.color(Red);` is a lot easier to use and pass around as a parameter than `AbstractShapeBuilder<Circle, CircleBuilder> s = new CircleBuilder(); s.color(Red);`

Using the `new` keyword like this allows users of the subtype to get the benefits of knowing what the specific type is, and also allows users of the supertype to operate polymorphically, without introducing *any* additional complexity for the caller. This technique is used in the .NET Framework all over the place and you don't even notice it because it's so intuitive - that's how [SqlConnection.CreateCommand()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421868/425852) and [OleDbConnection.CreateCommand()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421868/425852) implement the same base method even though they have different return types.

[Maybe Jon Skeet doesn't like using `new`,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421868/425852) but I feel that the generic version is significantly uglier, less readable, and more complicated to use.

Answer (score 0):

see: [How to return subtype in overridden method of subclass in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421851/how-to-return-subtype-in-overridden-method-of-subclass-in-c?rq=1)

Maybe you can use generics?

```
ShapeBuilder<T>
```

See the example from Stormenet.

Without using generics you are out of luck, so you answer is basically "No."

So then you are just looking at possible alternatives:

Another alternative (besides templates) is to use Object Initializers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

This also isn't what you want, but you can't always get what you want :)

```
    StudentName student2 = new StudentName
    {
        FirstName = "Craig",
        LastName = "Playstead",
    };
```

Comment: I read that link before I posted this. That basically says no, there is no clean way to do this in C#.